# How do you get Grails gsp support for Java localdatetime

Tags: grails, gsp, localdate

I am running Grails 3.3.8 with Java 8.v181.

I have a included hibernate-java8 and grails-java8 plugins, in build.gradle

```
//needed for java local datetime features set
compile "org.grails.plugins:grails-java8"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-java8"
```

I have a domain class like this

```
import cmdb.Customer

import java.time.LocalDateTime

class ServiceRequest {

    //Long id
    String requestIdentifier
    Customer customer
    String customerSummary
    String status
    LocalDateTime dateCreated = LocalDateTime.now()
    LocalDateTime requiredDate
    LocalDateTime authorisedDate
    String contactDetails
    String priority = "normal"
    BillOfMaterials bom

    String toString() {
        "ServiceRequest (id:$id, customer:$customerSummary, status:$status)"
    }

    static constraints = {
        requestIdentifier size:3..30, unique:true, nullable:false
        customer nullable:true
        customerSummary nullable:true
        status nullable :false
        dateCreated nullable:false
        requiredDate nullable:true
        authorisedDate nullable:true
        contactDetails nullable:true
        priority nullable:true
        bom nullable:true

    }
 }
```

When you run that att with default controller and scaffolding views all you get is this - there is no rendering for datetime.

The dbconsole shows that defaulting mapping into jdbc is using H2 timestamp type and the dateCreated is persisted - but doesn't show in the form.  the other two localdatetime do - but have no rendering in the list view and you can't edit in the edit form.

Using older Date format - does render a time field selector - is localdatetime still not supported in GSP views, even with Java8 support enabled?

It is frustrating to have to drop back to use Date for views as my other entities/DT objects etc are using localdatetime.

[image]

Comment: I created a domain class in 3.1.8 with just a String and a LocalDateTime field & the LocalDateTime field renders on all views like 2018-10-02T14:02:07.321, I was going to suggest using custom field rendering, assuming you're using the fields plugin, https://grails-fields-plugin.github.io/grails-fields/latest/guide/index.html#customizingFieldRendering

Comment: i have included fields 2.2.8, java8 and hibernate java8 plugins in build.gradle

Comment: compile 'org.grails.plugins:fields:2.2.8'
    //needed for java local datetime features set
    compile "org.grails.plugins:grails-java8"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-java8"

Comment: if i change LocalDateTime fields to  Date, then the field is rendered. however put LocalDateTime back and i get nothing - as shown above for requiredDate, and authorisedDate fields in domain class