# Grails scaffolding, still can't process java8 localdateTime in edit forms, nor can it do Map property

Tags: grails, scaffolding, localdate

I am using Grails v3.3.9, latest grails hibernate 8 and grails plugins in build.gradle, along with java8 plugin, fields plugin (didn't make any difference) and Hibernate 8.

```
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.5.Final"
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-java8', version: '5.1.5.Final'
compile "org.grails.plugins:gsp"
compile 'org.grails.plugins:grails-java8:1.2.3'  //java 8 features including datetime in GSP
compile 'org.grails.plugins:fields:2.2.10'
```

I've tried this on my Domain model which extends an abstract class with LocalDateTime

```
abstract class Agreement {

    String contractReference
    String status
    LocalDateTime contractSignedDate
    LocalDateTime lastUpdated   //updated by framework
    LocalDateTime dateCreated   //updated by framework

    static constraints = {
        contractReference nullable:false
        status nullable:false
        contractSignedDate nullable:true
    }
}
```

and concrete class here

```
class MaintenanceAgreement extends Agreement {

    String level
    Map category = [:]  //p1 to p5 and sla details 

    //static belongsTo = [serviceProvider : OrgRoleInstance, maintainer: OrgRoleInstance]

    // implemented as unidirectional many to one !  mag point to org
    static belongsTo = [maintainer: OrgRoleInstance]

    static constraints = {
        level nullable:false
        //serviceProvider nullable:true
        maintainer nullable:false   //ref to maintainer party

        category nullable:false
    }
}
```

If I have a record in Db from bootstrap with null column - grails just doesn't how any field holder for null entry.  Go back to bootstrap and manually create a value, restart.

At least this time list and show rendering put an actual on the form

[image]

However when you go to create a new form (or the edit action) you get this.  The contractSigned (localDateTime) **has no editor**, and lastly the domain model has a property category as a Map, and there is **no editor** for Map column.

[image]

This is a real problem.  I can revert back to trying to use Date but that's a retrograde step really, and the platform suggests the new data time formats are supported.  The Map column to think what my fallback for that might.

Am I missing something here that makes this work ?  or do I have re raise as defect ?

I ran into this in previous 3.3.8 build here also with no resolution to data time issue

[previous record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52589049/how-do-you-get-grails-gsp-support-for-java-localdatetime)

see also previous ask for feature here

[make java new dates first class citizen in grails](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10141)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `LocalDateTime` in you class for data type. You might not able to edit that. Use `Date` type instead. Then grails itself will provide you date-picker to add and edit as well. If you need to extract current date time in GSP you can use `${new Date()` as value of that field.

Comment: Syed, sadly this is not ideal.  the new Java8 (and beyond ) libraries have  better control and less inconsistency that the original Date type.    new LocaldateTime etc are going away - quite the oppoosite, and alot of new developers to the platform will start in this direction.  Grails as a framework for web apps should readily provide this capability without leaving developers stranded. The fields plugin now will render a localdatetime - but it won't let you edit one in an edit form.

Comment: ok started to try and look at this.  I've created a grails-app/views/temaplates/_fields/localDateTime folder and created a '_widget.gsp' template in that directory.  i've set a breakpoint (using intellij ultimate) on the 'out << "$attrs.name with value $attrs.value"' line in my gsp just to see if it gets here.  When i debug-app and use create action on domain class with a LocalDateTime - form opens and my widget doesnt fire the debugger.  so its now calling, finding the gsp ?  any ideas how to get started on this please ?

Comment: got the directory wrong.  Now added to grails-app/views/_fields and i can see an interaction (my _displayWidget.gsp with out << 'some text' is rendering to list) , but the debugger wont stop at break point.  its shows as grey circle with line through it.  Do i need to have a plugin to enable gsp debugging.